# bootstrap 4 forms, accessibility and error notices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a bootsrtap 4 form using the `grid` system.  This is not my main thing, I have significant eyesight issues and doing "pretty" is not really possible for me.  Basically I am open to all suggestions here.

What I think I want is the following:

- Each form control needs a `label`
- Each control should have an "error" `div` into which validation messages can be placed

For the moment, the most complex form section is for a full name.  I want separate fields for last, first and middle names.  Last and forst are required and middle is optional.  I have this so far:

```
    <form id="adultCreateForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div id="name" class="form-group row">
            <div class="rowHeader col-md-2">
                <span class="bold rowLabel col col-3">Name</span>
            </div>
            <div class=" rowContent col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3  lastNameDiv">
                        <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="lastName" name="lastName"
                               placeholder="Last Name" 
                               type="text" maxlength="64" 
                               pattern="[a-zA-Z' -]{1,32}" 
                               title="Required. 1-32 alpha chars plus space, hyphen and single-quote" 
                               required>
                        <div class='error'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3  firstNameDiv">
                        <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                        <input id="firstName" name="firstName"
                               placeholder="First Name" 
                               type="text" maxlength="64" 
                               pattern="[a-zA-Z' -]{1,32}" 
                               title="Required. 1-32 alpha chars plus space, hyphen and single-quote" 
                               required>
                        <div class='error'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 middleNameDiv">
                        <label for="middleName" class="sr-only">Middle Name</label>
                        <input id="middleName" name="middleName" 
                               placeholder="Middle Name" 
                               type="text" maxlength="64" 
                               pattern="[a-zA-Z' -]{1,32}" 
                               title="Required. 1-32 alpha chars plus space, hyphen and single-quote" 
                               required>
                        <div class='error'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inlineBlock floatRight">
            <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-warning floatRight">
                <strong>Cancel</strong>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

What I get is a visible "header" for Name and I get the three inputs with place holders in line on a standard monitor.  One issue is that the input fileds appear to slightly overlap.  Also, instead of rounded input box corners they are square.

I have tried different column widths but I am obviouls missing something fundamental.

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

remove `sr-only` class from the `label` element, you should be able to get what you are looking for.